# Average of HTML table content column and row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am stuck with this problem, where I need average of each column and each row like following:

```
7 9 8
5 7 9
6 6 8
```

to:

```
7 9 8 8
5 7 9 7
6 6 8 6.7
6 7.3 8.3
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside `scipt.js`:

```
(function () {
var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
var sum=0;
var row=table.rows;
console.log(row[0].innerText.split("  "));
var tr = document.createElement('tr');

for(var i=0, row; row.length>i; i++) {
    sum = sum + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
}

tr.insertCell(0).textContent = sum / 3;

table.appendChild(tr);

})();
```

I am new to JavaScript. Is there a better method to achieve this affect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `for` loops. Create an array filled with `0`, set value for each index within `for` loop, sum and average vertical columns following setting averages of rows. Note, to include average of averages at cell of last row, adjust `len` to `len = cols.length`, that is, remove `-1` at `len = cols.length -1` at last `for` loop.

```js
(function() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.rows;
  // store columns sums
  var cols = Array.from({length: row.length + 1}, () => 0);
  for (var i = 0; row.length > i; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = n = 0; j < row[i].cells.length; sum += n, cols[j] += n, j++) {
      n = +(row[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
    }
    row[i].insertCell(j)
    .innerHTML = "<b>" + (sum / row.length).toFixed(1) + "</b>";
    // set column values
    cols[cols.length - 1] += (sum / row.length -1);
  }
  // set column averages
  table.insertRow();
  var lastrow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
  // set `len` to `len = cols.length` to include average of averages
  for (var i = 0, len = cols.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var html = "<b>" + (cols[i] / len).toFixed(1) + "</b>";
    td.innerHTML = html;
    lastrow.appendChild(td);
  }
})();
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

## This should get you on the right track

This code works for horizontally figuring out the average. This is an example of how to iterate with a `for` loop through `HTML` elements, get their content as string and convert them to `ints`.

```
var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows=table.rows;

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
 var cells = rows[i].cells;
 var sum = 0;

 for(var x = 0; x < cells.length; x++){
  var cell = cells[x];
  sum += parseInt(cell.innerHTML);
 }
 var average = sum/cells.length;
 rows[i].innerHTML += "<td>"+average+"</td>";
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j37m2z7h/)

Answer (score 0):

You can to use `parseFloat((sum/3).toFixed(1))` to round the sum:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = table.rows;
var myTable2 = document.getElementById("myTable2");
var newRows = '';
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length ; i++ ){
    let numbers = rows[i].cells;
  //console.log(numbers[0]innerHTML);
    newRows += "<tr>";
    let sum = 0;
    for (let j = 0 ; j < numbers.length ; j++){
      sum += parseInt(numbers[j].innerHTML);
      newRows += "<td>" + numbers[j].innerHTML + "</td>";
    };
    newRows += "<td><b>" + parseFloat((sum/3).toFixed(1)) + "</b></td></tr>";
};
//console.log(newRows);
myTable2.innerHTML = newRows;
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
<table>
  
<table border="1" id="myTable2">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is the following:

```
// assigning the result of the immediately-invoked function expression
// (IIFE), the format of - among others - (function(){})()
// the final parentheses allow us to pass an argument to the enclosed
// function, to the 'averageTables' variable for subsequent use if
// required:
let averageTables = (function(opts) {

  /* the 'opts' Object passed as the argument is as follows:
    {
      // String: the CSS selector to identify the relevant
      // <table> elements:
      'table': '#myTable, #myOtherStrangelyIdenticalTable',

      // Boolean: whether or not you want to see the last cell
      // in the <table> the average of the averages column
      'hideAverageOfAverages': false,

      // String: the class-name to add to the <td> containing
      // the average of each <tr>:
      'rowAverageClassName': 'rowAverage',

      // String: the class-name to add to the <td> containing
      // the average of each column:
      'columnAverageClassName': 'columnAverage',

      // String: the class-name to add to the <td> containing
      // the average of the column of averages:
      'averageOfAveragesClassName': 'averageOfAverage',

      // Number: the number of decimal places to which the
      // averages should be rounded:
      'decimalPlaces': 1
    }
  */

  // here we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve the relevant
  // <table> elements, assuming that the opts.table selector results
  // in a selection of <table> elements:
  let tableElements = document.querySelectorAll(opts.table),

  // we use Array.from() to convert the NodeList from
  // document.querySelectorAll() into an Array:
    allTables = Array.from(tableElements),

  // here we create a new <td> element:
    newCell = document.createElement('td'),

  // here we find the divisor, and multiplier, for
  // accurately (insofar as JavaScript can) round
  // to a set number of decimal places:
    nDecimals = Math.pow(10, opts.decimalPlaces),

  // and initialise some empty variables for later
  // use:
    rows, column, cell, average;

  // here we use the Element.classList interface to add
  // the class-name passed in from the opts Object:
  newCell.classList.add(opts.rowAverageClassName);

  // we iterate over the Array of <table> elements using
  // Array.prototype.forEach():
  allTables.forEach(function(table) {

    // 'table' is a reference to the current <table> of the
    // Array of <table> elements over which we're iterating.

    // we cache the <tr> elements, as an Array, recovered
    // from the HTMLTableElement.rows collection:
    rows = Array.from(table.rows);

    // iterating over that Array of <tr> elements:
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      // 'row' is a reference to the current <tr> element
      // from the Array of <tr> elements over which we're
      // iterating.

      // here we use Array.from() to create an Array of the
      // <td> elements that are the element-children of the
      // current <tr> element:
      average = Array.from(row.children)

        // we then use Array.prototype.reduce() to reduce
        // that Array to a single element:
        .reduce(function(value, currentCell) {
          // 'value': the current value of the reduce method,
          // (initialised to 0 as the final argument following
          // the anonymous function),
          // currentCell: the current <td> element of the
          // Array of <td> elements over which we're iterating.

          // here we add the currently-held value to the result
          // of retrieving the text-content of the current <td>,
          // and using String.prototype.trim() to remove any
          // leading or trailing white-space, and then passing
          // that resultant String to parseFloat() to convert
          // a numeric String to a number (if possible); note
          // that there are no sanity checks, so if the text
          // cannot be converted to a Number then the result of
          // reduce() will be either undefined or NaN.
          // This approach, obviously finds the sum of the text
          // of all <td> elements:
          return value + parseFloat(currentCell.textContent.trim());

      // following the summation, then, we divide it by the number
      // of <td> elements within the <tr> to find the average:
      }, 0) / row.children.length;

      // we clone the created <td> element:
      cell = newCell.cloneNode();

      // and set its text-content to the result of the following,
      // in which we multiply the found average by the value of
      // nDecimals, and use Math.round() on the result, and then
      // divide by the result of nDecimals to find the result to
      // the user-defined number of decimal places (using
      // Number.toFixed(n) will simply cut off the number without
      // rounding, which is possibly not a big issue in your use-case):
      cell.textContent = Math.round(average * nDecimals ) / nDecimals ;

      // here we append the created, cloned <td> to the current <tr>:
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    // here we simply find the last <tr> element in the <table>,
    // and then clone that node, including its children, using
    // cloneNode(true); it's worth remembering that
    // document.querySelector() returns only a single node, if any,
    // which is the first element it finds that matches the supplied
    // CSS selector:
    let newRow = table.querySelector('tr:last-child').cloneNode(true);

    // here we use Array.from() to convert the NodeList of newRow.children
    // into an Array, and then use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate
    // over that Array:
    Array.from(newRow.children).forEach(function(cell, index) {
      // 'cell': a reference to the current <td> element of the
      // Array of <td> elements over which we're iterating,
      // 'index': the index of the current <td> within the Array
      // over which we're iterating.

      // retrieving a collection of <td> elements using the CSS
      // td:nth-child(), and interpolating the result of 'index + 1'
      // as the argument to :nth-child(); we add 1 to the index
      // because JavaScript is zero-based, whereas CSS is one-based; and
      // then using Array.from() to convert that collection into
      // an Array:
      column = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')'));

      // here we calculate the average exactly the same way as above,
      // but over the columns rather than the rows:
      average = column.reduce(function(value, currentCell) {
        return value + parseFloat(currentCell.textContent.trim());
      }, 0) / column.length;

      // we set the cell's text-content exactly the same way
      // as above (which in DRY terms is, admittedly, ridiculous):
      cell.textContent = Math.round(average * 10) / 10;

      // here we add the user-supplied class-name to the
      // column-average <td> elements:
      cell.classList.add(opts.columnAverageClassName);

    });

    // and we then append the newRow to the current <table>
    // element:
    table.appendChild(newRow);

    // here we find the :last-child of the newly-added row,
    // which is the <td> containing the average of the
    // averages column:
    let averageOfAverage = newRow.querySelector('td:last-child');

    // here we set the display of that <td>, if the user wants to
    // hide the cell (opts.hideAverageOfAverages is true) then
    // we set the display style to 'none'; otherwise (if
    // opts.hideAverageOfAverages is anything other than exactly true)
    // we set the display to that of 'table-cell':
    averageOfAverage.style.display = opts.hideAverageOfAverages === true ? 'none' : 'table-cell';

    // and then we add the requisite, user-defined, class-name:
    averageOfAverage.classList.add(opts.averageOfAveragesClassName);
  });

  // at this point we return the Array of <tables> found
  // to the calling context if the user wants to have
  // use to them for any other reason:
  return allTables;

})({
  'table': '#myTable, #myOtherStrangelyIdenticalTable',
  'hideAverageOfAverages': false,
  'rowAverageClassName': 'rowAverage',
  'columnAverageClassName': 'columnAverage',
  'averageOfAveragesClassName': 'averageOfAverage',
  'decimalPlaces': 1
});
```

```js
let averageTables = (function(opts) {
  let tableElements = document.querySelectorAll(opts.table),
    allTables = Array.from(tableElements),
    newCell = document.createElement('td'),
    nDecimals = Math.pow(10, opts.decimalPlaces),
    rows, column, cell, average;

  newCell.classList.add(opts.rowAverageClassName);

  allTables.forEach(function(table) {

    rows = Array.from(table.rows);
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      average = Array.from(row.children).reduce(function(value, currentCell) {
        return value + parseFloat(currentCell.textContent.trim());
      }, 0) / row.children.length;

      cell = newCell.cloneNode();
      cell.textContent = Math.round(average * nDecimals) / nDecimals;

      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    let newRow = table.querySelector('tr:last-child').cloneNode(true);
    Array.from(newRow.children).forEach(function(cell, index, all) {
      column = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')'));

      average = column.reduce(function(value, currentCell) {
        return value + parseFloat(currentCell.textContent.trim());
      }, 0) / column.length;

      cell.textContent = Math.round(average * nDecimals) / nDecimals;

      cell.classList.add(opts.columnAverageClassName);

    });
    table.appendChild(newRow);
    let averageOfAverage = newRow.querySelector('td:last-child');

    averageOfAverage.style.display = opts.hideAverageOfAverages === true ? 'none' : 'table-cell';
    averageOfAverage.classList.add(opts.averageOfAveragesClassName);
  });

  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(opts.table));

})({
  'table': '#myTable, #myOtherStrangelyIdenticalTable',
  'hideAverageOfAverages': false,
  'rowAverageClassName': 'rowAverage',
  'columnAverageClassName': 'columnAverage',
  'averageOfAveragesClassName': 'averageOfAverage',
  'decimalPlaces': 1
});
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}
td {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
td.rowAverage {
  color: red;
}
td.columnAverage {
  color: limegreen;
}
td.columnAverage.rowAverage.averageOfAverage {
  color: rebeccapurple;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="myOtherStrangelyIdenticalTable">
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/180om6cx/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:last-child` selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo).
  - [`:nth-child()` selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
  - [Conditional (ternary) Operator (`expression ? ifTrue : ifFalse`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/conditional_operator).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).
  - [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).
  - [`HTMLTableElement.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows).
  - [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).
  - [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).
  - [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`parentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).
  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, iterate over the rows and get the last column populated first.

Once the average column for rows are updated, iterate over the nth column and update the average.

Here is a sample :

```js
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    var rows = document.querySelector("#myTable").rows;
    [].forEach.call(rows, (row) => {
      let currentSum = 0;
      let cells = row.cells;
      [].forEach.call(cells, (currentVal) => {
        currentSum += parseInt(currentVal.innerText, 10);
      });
      appendElement(row, (currentSum / cells.length).toFixed(1));
    });

    let columnCount = document.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(1)>td").length;
    let rowContent = document.createElement("tr");
    let table = document.querySelector("#myTable");

    for (let idx = 0; idx < columnCount; idx++) {
      let columns = document.querySelectorAll("tr>td:nth-child(" + (idx + 1) + ")");
      let currentSum = 0;
      [].forEach.call(columns, (column) => {
        currentSum += parseInt(column.innerText, 10);
      });
      appendElement(rowContent, (currentSum / rows.length).toFixed(1))
    }
    table.appendChild(rowContent);
  }
};

function appendElement(parent, sum) {
  let cellEle = document.createElement("td");
  cellEle.innerText = sum;
  cellEle.classList.add("bold");
  parent.appendChild(cellEle);
}
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```